# add user role selection to registration form

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

I need to add a select box or something like that into registration form in order to let my users to select custom roles I have defined.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you could try some thing like this.

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'my_register_form' );

function my_register_form() { 
?>

<select>
<option>Role_1</option>
<option>Role_2</option>
<option>Role_3</option>
</select>

<?php

}
```